# Error when uploading laravel project to server - failed to load resource

Tags: php, laravel

I have made a directory under public_html/laravel which contains my public files

I have uploaded the rest of the files to /laravel

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

My index.php file:

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));



require __DIR__.'../lsapp/vendor/autoload.php';



$app = require_once __DIR__.'../lsapp/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comment: enable dev mode, check your logs

Comment: Did you add .htaccess file ?

Comment: @rufatZZ did you know how to upload laravel project to the server?

Comment: You can use `ssh` or `FTP`. I just once uploaded laravel project to the server with FTP.